# SSIS Data Flow XML source XSD for yahoo finance all currencies

Tags: ssis, xsd, yahoo, forex

I aimed to import spot forex data from following link
https://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote
I use SSIS xml source, however I don't have xsd for import.
Using inline shema won't work
Can u pls help me out?

Comment: xsd generator like this did not help https://www.freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.html#ad-output

Comment: Using SSIS XML source editors's "Generate XSD" function gave column type, other colums are missing..

Comment: Based on freeformatter.com/xsd-generator.htmlxsd I got a list instead of a table. I used pivot to use the data. It works.